# TouchEvents in andengine HUD on multiple areas

Tags: android, andengine, hud

I have an andengine scene set up with a HUD. The HUD has 2 touch areas (rectangles). The `onAreaTouched()` works for both of them individually but when the left touch area is being touched the one on the right does not respond to touches and vice versa. It looks as if the two touch areas are running on the same thread. I need the two touch areas to respond simultaneously. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have multitouch activated?
Add this in the onCreateEngineOptions after creating your engineOptions

```
        yourEngineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. Been trying to figure out what's wrong for 2 days. Such a simple solution.! I don't know what the harm is in having this enabled by default?